# ¿Cómo puedo agregar un aviso de confirmación al darle retroceso en mi navbar en React Native?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, expo

Tengo una aplicación en React Native que se centra en formularios en general. En la parte superior de la pantalla tengo una barra de navegación con un botón que permite retroceder en la navegación de la aplicación. Sin embargo, me gustaría implementar una funcionalidad adicional cuando se hace clic en ese botón mientras se está llenando un formulario.

Mi objetivo es mostrar un mensaje emergente (modal) que solicite al usuario confirmar si desea salir del formulario en curso. Dependiendo de la opción elegida por el usuario, se realizará la acción correspondiente: salir del formulario o permanecer en él para continuar completándolo.

Básicamente, mi programa tiene un componente con el Navbar y en el código principal, dónde llamo a los demás componentes, tengo mi stack navigator, entonces dependiendo de el componente (si es de formulario) me haga ese modal de confirmación.

Mi Navbar es el siguiente:

```
const Navbar = () => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Logo style={styles.logo}></Logo>
      <VidaAssistance style={styles.text}></VidaAssistance>
    </View>
  );
};
```

En mi Stack Navigator tengo lo siguiente:

```
<Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen
        name="formularioMedicos"
        component={FormularioMedicosComponent}
        options={{
          headerTitle: props => <Navbar {...props} />,
        }}
      />
</Stack.Navigator>
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes lograrlo utilizando el evento beforeRemove dentro del hook useEffect de react.

```
const [condicionParaEvitarElMensaje, setCondicionParaEvitarElMensaje] = useState(false);

React.useEffect(
  () =>
    navigation.addListener('beforeRemove', (e) => {
      if (condicionParaEvitarElMensaje) {
        return;
      }

      e.preventDefault();

      Alert.alert(
        'Seguro que deseas salir?',
        'Tus cambios no serán guardados. Estás seguro de salir?',
        [
          { text: "No salir", style: 'cancel', onPress: () => {} },
          {
            text: 'Salir',
            style: 'destructive',
            onPress: () => navigation.dispatch(e.data.action),
          },
        ]
      );
    }),
  [navigation, condicionParaEvitarElMensaje]
);
```

En el ejemplo se utiliza el listener para el evento beforeRemove, en este ocurre una condición por si se necesita evitar mostrar la alerta, luego se utiliza e.preventDefault() para evitar que ocurra la acción predeterminada por ReactNavigator y finalmente se muestra la alerta de salida.

Este código lo implementarías en el componente que quieras que muestre la alerta antes de salir.